# Search for a comment on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, search

How do you search for a friend's (or your own) comment on a wall post from months ago on Facebook?

Comment: some one told me online to hit either shift or control and something else that gives you a box to type the name in but I don't remember what it was. I was trying to find out by searching for it maybe this will remind someone of it. what it did was highlight your name and made it easier to find on the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently the only way seems to be browse and manually search via the Friend's connection

```
http://www.facebook.com/yourname?and=friendsname&sk=comments
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of scrolling, thanks.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore, I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the post and type command "F" if you're on a Mac, it will bring up a finder window and you can search the persons name on there.